# Error undefined method `categories' for #<User:0x00000103047730>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This happen in my app/controllers/categories_controller.rb:3:in `create'
I plan to develop a blog and each user can create fews categories for their micropost. Therefore each micropost can only has one category. I have 3 table :user, microposts and category.  My intention is to have a user to add category at user profile page.

```
model/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user    
    attr_accessible :category
end
```

model/user.rb

```
has_many :category, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :category, :reject_if =>lambda {|a| a[:category].blank?}
```

categoriesController

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
def create
    @category = current_user.categories.new(params[:category])
    if @category.save 
        flash[:success] = "Category created!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        flash[:error] = "Category not created."
        render @user
    end
  end
end
```

usersController

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
    @category = @user.category.new
end
```

user show.html

```
<%= form_for @category do |f|%>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id  %>
        <%= f.label :category ,"Category:"%>
        <%=h f.text_field :category %><br />
        <%= f.submit "Add Category" %>  
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `User` model you have relation

```
has_many :category
```

But in controller get from user categor **ies**

```
current_user.categories
```

Rename relation name to `has_many :categories`.

Comment: thank you! it worked! I kinda confused when should I use plural or singular with the model and controllers.